# How to create a generic Network Resource State classes in dart?

Tags: dart

In Kotlin, I create generic classes to handle data fetching network states as following:

```
sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val error: String? = null
) {
    class Success<T>(data: T?) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Loading<T> : Resource<T>()
    class Error<T>(error: String) : Resource<T>(error = error)
}
```

Whenever I want to create an object of one of the available states, I can do that using `Resource.Success<T>` for example, not just `Success<T>`. I think this is a cleaner way to make my code easier to follow up with and understand.

I tried to achieve the same using dart, but I am stuck. I only created class the following way which is not really the same as what I want.

Can someone guide me on how to achieve my target using best practices?

```
abstract class ResourceState<T> {
  T? data;
  String? error;
  ResourceState({this.data, this.error});
}
class ResourceLoading<T> extends ResourceState<T>{
  ResourceLoading() : super();
}
class ResourceError extends ResourceState {
  ResourceError(String error) : super(error: error);
}
class ResourceSuccess extends ResourceState {
  ResourceSuccess(dynamic data) : super(data: data);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use named constructors:

```dart
class Resource<T> {
  T ? data;
  String? error;
  Resource({this.data, this.error});
  Resource.success(this.data);
  Resource.error(this.error);
  Resource.loading();

  bool get isLoading => error == null && data == null;
  bool get isSuccess => data != null;
  bool get isError => error != null;
}
```

This allows you to create a success as `Resource<T>.success(value)` and an error as `Resource<T>.error("Badness overwhelming!")`.

The type argument to the `error` constructor doesn't matter if you'll never add a data value. You could make it `Resource<Never>.error("badness!")`.

I left the unnamed constructor public, in case you want to use it, but it's not *necessary* and can be removed.

If you want the class to really be sealed, you won't want any public generative (non-factory) constructors.
In that case, I'd do it as:

```dart
class Resource<T> {
  T ? data;
  String? error;
  Resource._({this.data, this.error});
  factory Resource.success(T data) => Resource._(data: data);
  factory Resource.error(this.error) => Resource._(error: error);
  factory Resource.loading() => Resource._();

  // ...
}
```

This class cannot be extended because it has no public generative constructor available to do the super-constructor call that a subclass is require to do.
Its interface can still be implemented, because any Dart interface can.