# Value of type 'Resource<dynamic>' can't be returned as T where T extends Resource

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's my program (you can run it as a dart file):

```
/// Fetches data from TestRepository and shows result
main () async {
  final repository = TestRepository();
  final resource = await repository.fetchString();
  if (resource.isError) {
    print("| Error: ${resource.error}");
  } else {
    print("| Success: ${resource.data}");
  }
}

/// A class to get Success or Error responses
class Resource<S> {
  final S? _data;
  final String? _message;

  Resource.success(S data)
      : _data = data,
        _message = null;

  Resource.error(String message)
      : _data = null,
        _message = message;

  bool get isError => _message != null;

  S get data => _data!;

  String get error => _message!;
}

/// A sample repository class to use API and handle errors
class TestRepository {
  Future<Resource<String>> fetchString() {
    return _dummyApiCall().useErrorHandler();
  }

  /// Dummy API Call mimicking
  Future<Resource<String>> _dummyApiCall() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    if (true) {
      // to mimic an exception so that we can catch it
      throw Exception("Error Occurred");
    }
    return Resource.success("Hello World");
  }
}

/// An extension to wrap Resource Futures with error handler
extension FutureResourceExt<T extends Resource> on Future<T> {
  Future<T> useErrorHandler() {
    return onError((error, stacktrace) => handleError(error));
  }
}

/// A function to handle errors thrown by Future.onError
T handleError<T extends Resource>(dynamic error) {
  return Resource.error("Error: $error");
}
```

I have a code error on following line:

```
return Resource.error("Error: $error");
```

The error says:

*A value of type 'Resource<dynamic>' can't be returned from the function 'handleError' because it has a return type of 'T'*

If I change the implementation to add `as T` to above statement, code error disappears and gets thrown on runtime.

*Unhandled Exception: type 'Resource<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Resource<SomeDataType>' in type cast*

I don't know why can I not assign `Resource` to `T extends Resource` return type.
How should I implement `Resource` class such that I can do this without knowing `S` type of `Resource`?

Comment: how do you call handleError?

Comment: what does handleError return? a Resource with T type or a value of T?

Comment: @eamirho3ein I have updated the question with 'how handleError is called'. `handleError()` returns `Resource<dynamic>` I think.

Comment: Could you please explain the need for generic type in handlError ? if you are already returning a Resource which taking dynamic type in its contructor?
Maybe this is what you want `Resource<T> handleError<T>(dynamic error)` ?

Comment: @HKN I updated the question to include a minimal runnable sample. Even if I use your suggestion, the code error or thrown error stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the line with error code:

```
return Resource.error("Error: $error");
```

Here's the solution:

```
return Resource<Never>.error("Error: $error") as T;
```

I received a hint from [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69073159/3682535). Never knew something like `Never` existed.